# php variable in div get div vlaue in javascript or jquery how it is possible

Tags: javascript, php

her is code

```
<div id="myDiv" class="myDiv"> 
    <?php   date("Y-m-d h:i: a", time()+$country[0]->timezone_offset); ?>  </div>
```

javascript code

```
 myDivObj = document.getElementById("myDiv");
if ( myDivObj ) {
   alert ( myDivObj.innerHTML ); 
}else{
   alert ( "not Found" );
}
```

i apply this code then show noyhing
i get the value from database into div and get div value in javascript variable

how to get value of div in javscript
where is problem

Comment: you need to add echo `<?php echo date.........`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you get data in div, You can use the script below to get div value

```
<script>
var divValue=document.getElementById('myDiv').innerHTML;
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code is not working because you don't print the php date.

Use `echo` to display the date into your div :

```
<?php echo date("Y-m-d h:i: a", time()+$country[0]->timezone_offset); ?>
```